# How to start new activity from tab control?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabcontrol

I have home activity which have tab control and on first tab the main activity is shown. On main tab i have buttons which will redirect to another activity.
and cannot redirect to another activity.

```
public class Main1 extends Fragment 
{
    ImageView saving, loan;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        saving = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.imgSavingCollection);
        loan = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.imgLoanCollection);

        saving.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) container);
        loan.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) container);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main1, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imgSavingCollection:
                Intent savingactivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), SavingCollection.class);
                startActivity(savingactivity);
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: when i run the activity the app stopped automatically.

Comment: @Gopal see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your code like,

```
public class Main1 extends Fragment 
{
  ImageView saving, loan;

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main1, container, false);

  saving = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgSavingCollection);
  loan = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgLoanCollection);

saving.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent savingactivity = new Intent(getActivity(), SavingCollection.class);
            startActivity(savingactivity);
        }
    });

 return rootView;
}

}
```

also check your `manifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".SavingCollection"/>
```

this may helps you

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
Intent savingactivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), SavingCollection.class);
startActivity(savingactivity);
```

add this

```
Intent savingactivity = new Intent(getActivity(), SavingCollection.class);
startActivity(savingactivity );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 Intent savingactivity = new Intent(getActivity(), SavingCollection.class);
 startActivity(savingactivity);
```

Replace `v.getContext()` to `getActivity()`.

and Define your layout line upper side

`View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main1, container, false);`

**Full code :**

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main1, container, false);

saving = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.imgSavingCollection);
    loan = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.imgLoanCollection);

    saving.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) container);
    loan.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) container);


    return v;
```

Comment: still error is comming  Process: mobileofflineapp.gopalchudal.mobileofflineapp, PID: 2425
                                                                                             java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
                                                                                                 at mobileofflineapp.gopalchudal.mobileofflineapp.Main1.onCreateView(Main1.java:21)
                                       android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)

Comment: Your Initialization may be doing wrong way post your xml code here.

Answer (score 0):

problem may be with v.getContext(), so just replace it by getActivity() when you declaring intent.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with your onCreateView, replace below code with your onCreateView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup     container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main1, container, false);
  saving = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgSavingCollection);
  loan = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgLoanCollection);

  saving.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) container);
  loan.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) container);


  return v;
}
```